# Clang fails to expand parameter pack in std::function instantiation

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17, variadic-templates

The snippet of code compiled with `std=c++17` as the only compiler flag ...

- ... compiles successfully with GCC 9.1. [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/QKJomx)
- ... issues a compiler error with Clang 8.0.0 (error below snippet). [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/S7tB5K)

**Question:** is this a bug in the Clang compiler or is GCC wrong to accept this code or is something else at play?

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T>
    using Int = int;

    // Function that accepts as many 'int' as there are template parameters
    using Function = std::function< void(Int<Ts>...) >;

    // Tuple of as many 'int' as there are template parameters
    using Tuple = std::tuple< Int<Ts>... >;

    auto bar(Function f)
    {
        std::apply(f, Tuple{}); // Error with Clang 8.0.0
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto foo = Foo<char, bool, double>{};
    foo.bar([](int, int, int){});
}
```

---

What strikes me as odd is that Clang's error indicates it successfully aliased `Tuple` as `std::tuple<int, int, int>` but it wrongly aliases `Function` as just `std::function<void(int)>`, with only one instead of three arguments.

```
In file included from <source>:2:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0/functional:54:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0/tuple:1678:14: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke'
      return std::__invoke(std::forward<_Fn>(__f),
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../include/c++/8.3.0/tuple:1687:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__apply_impl<std::function<void (int)> &, std::tuple<int, int, int>, 0, 1, 2>' requested here
      return std::__apply_impl(std::forward<_Fn>(__f),
                  ^
<source>:19:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::apply<std::function<void (int)> &, std::tuple<int, int, int> >' requested here
        std::apply(f, Tuple{}); // Error
             ^
<source>:26:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'Foo<char, bool, double>::bar' requested here
    foo.bar([](int, int, int){});
```

---

## Additional Research

As other users in the comments already pointed out, making the `Int` template alias dependent on the type `T` fixes the issue:

```
template <typename T>
using Int = std::conditional_t<true, int, T>;
```

Something else I found out, just referring to the `Function` type from the outside also makes it work as expected/desired:

```
int main()
{
    auto f = Foo<char, bool, double>::Function{};
    f = [](int, int, int){};
}
```

Comment: [`Function` is actually right in the sense of its declaration](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eeff5b8f94df02e8) but something blows up somewhere else

Comment: Bug of clang for me. Code seems not ill formed.

Comment: Also why isn't `std::apply` working for me -.-

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: clang version on coliru is  5.0.0-3~16.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh lol

Comment: I think Clang doesn't like the fact that `T` isn't being used the type alias. A short way around this is `template <typename T>
    using Int = decltype(sizeof(T), 0);`

Comment: As the bug with `void_t`.

Comment: This also seems to work: `template <typename T> using Int = std::conditional_t<true, int, T>;`. Coliru's clang++ is still choking on `std::apply` though

Comment: It seems that Clang treats `std::function< void(Int<Ts>...) >` as an instantiation-dependent but not (type-)dependent type, so the type of everything related to `Function` is determined at definition time instead of at instantiation time. https://godbolt.org/z/rMLsyA

Comment: @cpplearner It still strikes me as very odd that everything works fine for the `Tuple` type alias then; somehow, Clang is perfectly fine with that one.
Additionally, and I have added this to the question, I also found out that just referring to `Foo<…>::Function` from outside the class works just fine, weird huh?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I also found this out by referring to `Foo<…>::Function` from outside the class and then it behaves as a function taking three integers... and even the `Tuple` alias works just fine. A bug it is then!

Comment: Anyone knows what this status ‘CD4’ mean?
1558 CD4 Unused arguments in alias template specializations Unknown

https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html

Comment: @MaartenBamelis Yep deffo. Nasty!

Comment: @Hui [_"CD4: A DR/DRWP or Accepted/WP issue not resolved in C++14 but included in the Committee Draft advanced for balloting at the June, 2014 WG21 meeting."_](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html) Not sure it's relevant though

Comment: Update: Bug was logged for this: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42654 (as Maarten asked me in person)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: it's a clang bug, but there's also a bug in the standard.

First be aware that in C++, templates are handled in two steps:

1. Constructs that are not *dependent* on the template parameters are built when the enclosing template is defined.
2. Constructs that are dependent are built when the enclosing template is instantiated.

Now, it seems that clang treats `std::function< void(Int<Ts>...) >` as a non-dependent  type, with the following reasoning:

1. `Int<Ts>` is a non-dependent type (correct).
2. Thus, pack expansion containing `Int<Ts>` (i.e. `Int<Ts>...`) is also a non-dependent "type" (?).
3. Because all components of `void(Int<Ts>...)` are non-dependent, it is a non-dependent type (obviously incorrect).
4. Because the name `std::function` is non-dependent and the template argument `void(Int<Ts>...)` is a non-dependent non-pack-expansion type, `std::function< void(Int<Ts>...) >` is a non-dependent type.

(Note that the "non-pack-expansion" check makes it different from the `Tuple` case.)

Therefore, when `Foo` is defined, the type name `Function` is treated as naming a non-dependent type, and is immediately built, and pack expansion (which happens during instantiation) is not accounted. Consequently, all uses of `Function` is replaced with the "desugared" type `std::function< void(int) >`.

Furthermore, clang has the notion of *instantiation-dependent*, which means the construct is not dependent, but it still somehow involves the template parameters (e.g. the construct is only valid for some parameters). `std::function< void(Int<Ts>...) >` is treated as a instantiation-dependent type, so when the template is instantiated, clang still performs substitution for `using Function = std::function< void(Int<Ts>...) >`. As a result, `Function` gets the correct type, but this does not propagate to uses of `Function` in the definition of `Foo`.

---

Now heres the bug in the standard.

Whether a type is dependent is defined in [[temp.dep.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.type#9):

> A type is dependent if it is
>
> - a template parameter,
> - a member of an unknown specialization,
> - a nested class or enumeration that is a dependent member of the current instantiation,
> - a cv-qualified type where the cv-unqualified type is dependent,
> - a compound type constructed from any dependent type,
> - an array type whose element type is dependent or whose bound (if any) is value-dependent,
> - a function type whose exception specification is value-dependent,
> - denoted by a *simple-template-id* in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template arguments is a dependent
>     type or an expression that is type-dependent or value-dependent or is
>     a pack expansion [ Note: This includes an injected-class-name of a
>     class template used without a *template-argument-list*. — end note ] ,
>     or
> - denoted by `decltype(expression)`, where expression is type-dependent.

Note that it doesn't say that a function type whose parameter list contains pack expansions is a dependent type, only that "a compound type constructed from any dependent type" and "a function type whose exception specification is value-dependent" are dependent. Neither is helpful here.

Comment: A difficult matter but you explained the two bugs very well! I see no error in your reasoning, so I will accept this as the correct answer.